# windows 10. Некорректно отображаются окна

Tags: windows, windows-10

Всем привет. На работе админ дал учетку свежесозданную. Но, как говорится, есть нюанс.

### Проблема

Окна отображаются вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть огромная толстая рамка в цвет основного цвета темы, светлые участки.

Также есть странная рамка у некоторых элементов интерфейса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Предпринятые попытки решения

1. Редактирование темы [по этому совету](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5/c0e814d5-3138-4ed1-933e-1dc636be68e4)
2. Изменение в реестре параметра типа EnableWindowColorization
3. Dism, sfc
4. Перерыт весь раздел персонализации и спец вощможностей
5. Плюс еще несколько вариантов, которые пробовали админы, результата нет

### Вопрос

Что это может быть, в какую сторону смотреть, как это можно решить?

**P.S.:** Если понадобится доп. инфа -- скину.

Comment: Ну а у самого админа спросить не пробовал? Он походу решил сделать суперкастом или уже качнул суперкастом. В ванильной винде такого нет (ну самые свежие релизы не ковырял ещё).

Comment: Дрова на видео стоят? Есть в установленных прогах чё-нить, что пишет экран или следит за работником? Ну кроме энидеска.

Comment: @donRumata "Ну а у самого админа спросить не пробовал?" -- спросил, возились час, не помогло.  "Дрова на видео стоят?" -- стоят. "Есть в установленных прогах чё-нить, что пишет экран или следит за работником?" -- ничего такого не нашел. "Он походу решил сделать суперкастом" -- насчет этого точно не подскажу

Comment: А под его учёткой или любой другой - такая же хрень или только для твоей?

Comment: @donRumata до этого у меня была временная учетка, не подключенная к домену, на ней все было норм. Потом дали эту, и появилась проблема. Создали еще одну учетку -- та же история и с ней

Comment: Ну значит где-то админ накостомайзил лишнего. Тут надо уже смотреть какие gpo к тебе применяются и искать в них. К сожалению, не могу сказать чё это за история с онками, у меня точно такой фигни не было.

Comment: @donRumata, ваш совет помог, огромное спасибо, подробности описал в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, проблему удалось решить. Проверили gpo по совету @donRumata (огромное спасибо ему) через `GPResult` и оказалось что применяется политика `Применение конкретного файла стиля оформления или классического стиля Windows` по пути `Конфигурация пользователя -- Административные шаблоны -- Панель управления -- Персонализация` в Изменении групповых политик. Политику для домена отключили, применили стандартную тему винды на моей учетке, после чего интерфейс пришел в норму.